# unrecognized selector sent to instance when assigning delegate to my PieChartView

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hi I have searched and search and then I have decided to post it here - this question may be silly to you but it costs me already one day:(

So I am trying to use the XYPieChart to draw some pie charts, here some some codes from XYPieChart:

XYPieChart.h

```
@class XYPieChart;
@protocol XYPieChartDataSource <NSObject>
@required
- (NSUInteger)numberOfSlicesInPieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart;
- (CGFloat)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart valueForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@optional
- (UIColor *)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart colorForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (NSString *)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart textForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end

@protocol XYPieChartDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart willSelectSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart didSelectSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart willDeselectSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart didDeselectSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end
```

XYPieChart.m

```
@synthesize dataSource = _dataSource;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

And then in my own view controller XYPieChartViewTestViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XYPieChart.h"

@interface XYPieChartViewTestViewController : UIViewController <XYPieChartDelegate,      XYPieChartDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet XYPieChart *MyPieCharts;
@end
```

And XYPieChartViewTestViewController.m

```
#import "XYPieChartViewTestViewController.h"

@interface XYPieChartViewTestViewController ()
@end
@implementation XYPieChartViewTestViewController
@synthesize MyPieCharts = _MyPieCharts;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [_MyPieCharts setDelegate:self];
}
```

But when executing [_MyPieCharts setDelegate:self];, there is a dump:

2012-10-16 10:33:53.100 XYPieChartViewTest[3859:11303] -[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9040680
*** First throw call stack:
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

If I put a breakpoint at the line "[_MyPieCharts setDelegate:self];", and PO self._MyPieCharts.delegate, it says:

po self.MyPieCharts.delegate
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
The process has been returned to the state before execution.

I have uploaded the project [here](http://www.4shared.com/zip/dBCBCOJI/XYPieChartViewTest.html) since I cannot post screen shots.

Does this mean that self.MyPieCharts.delegate is not initialized? Do you have any idea what should I do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like MyPieCharts isn't connected in Interface Builder.

Comment: ...or connected but not defined as a `XYPieChart` in IB.

Comment: I am using Storyboard and I think as as you can see, I have defined in my view controller XYPieChartViewTestViewController.h : @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet XYPieChart *MyPieCharts;. And you can see in xcode, there is a "dot" at the right of the statement, so it means it was connected. It also shows up in "referencing outlets" when I click the view where I want to show the pie charts.

Comment: I have uploaded my porject to http://www.4shared.com/zip/dBCBCOJI/XYPieChartViewTest.html

Comment: @PhillipMills was right: you haven't changed Class property of XYPieChart in IB. So it's currently UIView and it should be XYPieChart.

Comment: @gareg I am sorry but still I do not get you. Could you maybe post some pictures? I am using Storyboard. You can even download my project at the link I have sent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the delegate to :

```
[_MyPieCharts setDelegate:XYPieChartDelegate];
```

Comment: I do not understand - I want to set the delegate of the pie chart view to myController, so I set [_MyPieCharts setDelegate:self] in myController.m's viewDidLoad(). What did you mean by your answer?